# Modify regex matches inside the replacement string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a problem with some regex to grab url's from a text and  modify all matches inside the replacement string again by a function.
The code below is a dummy example of what I want do to.
Is something like this possible?

```
var exp = /\b((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[\S]*)/g;
text = text.replace(exp, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\""+parseUri("$1").host+"\"></a>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply a function as 2nd argument to `.replace`:

```
var exp = /\bhttps?:\/\/[\S]*/g;
text = text.replace(exp, function ($0) {
    return '<a href="' + $0 + '" title="' + parseUri($0).host + '"></a>'
});
```

(Note that `$0` is just a variable name, you can name it differently).

Check [`String.replace`'s documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for the meaning of the arguments to the replacement function. The first argument is the text capture by the whole regex. Then the next N arguments are the text captured by the N capturing groups in the regex.

I also take my liberty to rewrite the regex. Since `\b` is an assertion, no text will be consumed.